# Fetch and Replace properties with preg_replace

Tags: php, css, function, preg-replace, eof

I want to add tab to all the properties here but I don't know how to isolate the properties $1 is not working here.

Small tweak would make this working...

Thanks!

```php
$css = <<<EOF

body {
padding : 0px;
margin: 0px;
line-height: 10px;
}

p {
z-index: 9;
font-size: 10px;
}

EOF;


echo preg_replace('#({)(.*?)(})#', '\t$1' , $css);

/*

I'm expecting to get all properties with TAB :

    body {
         padding : 0px;
         margin: 0px;
         line-height: 10px;
    }

    p {
           z-index: 9;
           font-size: 10px;
    }
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$pattern = '~(?:{|\G(?!\A))\s*?;?\s*\K[^;}]+~';
echo preg_replace($pattern, "\t$0" , $css);
```

pattern details:

```
(?:          # possible beginings of the match
    {        # a curly bracket
  |          # OR
    \G(?!\A) # the end of a precedent match
)
\s*?;?\s*    # spaces (after the curly bracket) or ending ; of a property 
\K           # resets all the begining from match result
[^;}]+       # all that is not a closing curly bracket or a semi-colon
```

Comment: Perfect ! one small thing ... i'm getting extra empty line with tab before last }